# grffile / feynmp-auto compatibility in Texlive14

Tags: xetex, texlive, feynmp-auto

Since I reinstalled Texlive14 from scratch (I was using Texlive13 before) I ran into problems compiling my presentations that use both **grffile** and **feynmf-auto**. It appears that, due to the presence of **grffile**, the `testdiagram.1` output file is not found during compilation, while it is present in the folder and removing **grffile** suppresses the error and lets the diagram appear smoothly onto my slides.

I am also using **gmp** to make labels visible (no labels are there in the following MWE, though).

I use **xelatex** to compile, for other reasons. Here is a minimal example reproducing the error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{gmp}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    Test diagram
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{fmffile}{testdiagram}
            \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
                \fmfpen{thin}
                \fmfleft{a}
                \fmfright{lept1,lept2,nu}
                \fmf{fermion}{a,mixing}
                \fmf{fermion,label.side=left,label.dist=3thick,tension=2}{mixing,decay}
                \fmf{fermion,tension=0.8}{decay,nu}
                \fmf{phantom}{a,mixing}
                \fmf{wiggly,tension=2}{decay,Wdecay}
                \fmf{fermion}{lept1,Wdecay,lept2}
                \fmf{phantom}{lept1,Wdecay}
                \fmfv{l=$\gamma$,l.a=-90,decoration.shape=circle,decoration.size=4.2,decoration.filled=hatched}{mixing}
            \end{fmfgraph*}
        \end{fmffile}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here is the error stack I get:

> ERROR File 'testdiagram.1.' not found. \end{frame}
>
> ERROR Cannot determine size of graphic in testdiagram.1. (no BoundingBox). \end{frame}
>
> WARNING File 'testdiagram.1' not found
>
> WARNING Font shape 'OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available(Font) size <5> substituted
>
> WARNING Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 1.0pt have occurred.

Is this a bug that I should report, or can this be overcome somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Workaround: `\usepackage[multidot=false]{grffile}`

Comment: Weird: if I try the same with the `article` class (by just changing the document class and commenting `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`), it works. It doesn't depend on `feynmp-auto` in particular, however, because the same happens with `\usepackage{feynmp}`. For some reasons, when `beamer` is used, `grffile` makes LaTeX look for `testdiagram.1.` (with a trailing period).

Comment: @egreg: actually for me it fails anyway, regardless of the documentclass used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `grffile`, I'm afraid.

The minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grffile}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{testdiagram.1}
\end{document}
```

that stops with the same identical error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `testdiagram.1.' not found.
```

where `testdiagram.1` is a file built by Metapost. This only when compiling with XeLaTeX.

Passing the `multidot=false` option to `grffile` seems to be a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multidot=false]{grffile}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{testdiagram.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, `multidot=false` solves the problem also in beamer. I will try to file a bug report for `grffile`, because with this option it loses most of its purpose..
EDIT: I hadn't realized that @HeikoOberdiak already noticed.